# How to install multiple packages using apt-get via a Dockerfile

Tags: docker

So I am trying to make a basic Dockerfile, but when I run this it says

```
The command bin/sh -c sudo apt-get install git python-yaml python-jinja2 returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My question is what am I doing wrong here, and is it even allowed to do commands like 'cd' and 'source' from the Dockerfile?

```
FROM Ubuntu
MAINTAINER example

#install and source ansible
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install git python-yaml python-jinja2 python-pycurl
RUN sudo git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git
RUN sudo cd ansible
RUN sudo source ./hacking/env-setup
```

Answer (score 21):

Couple of pointers / comments here:

- It's `ubuntu` not `Ubuntu`
- From base `ubuntu` (and unfortunately, a lot of images) you don't need to use `sudo`, the default user is `root` (and in `ubuntu`, `sudo` is not included anyway)
- You want your `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` to be `RUN` as part of the same command, to prevent issues with Docker's layer cache
- You need to use the `-y` flag to apt-get install as the Docker build process runs non-interactively
- Few other points I could make about clearing up your apt-cache and other non-required artifacts after running the commands, but this should be enough to get going on

New Dockerfile (taking into account the above) would look something like:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER example

#install and source ansible
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    python-yaml \
    python-jinja2 \
    python-pycurl

RUN git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git
WORKDIR ansible/hacking
RUN chmod +x env-setup; sync \
    && ./env-setup
```

You might also find it useful to read the [Dockerfile best practises](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/).

Edit: [Larsks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40273532/559504) also makes some useful points about the state of the container not persisting between layers so you should go upvote him too!

Comment: Why not? It's another layer but it's no-op. It makes it more explicit for someone to read seeing which directory we're currently working in, rather than having to parse a load of `RUN` statements to see if there are `cd`s in there.

Comment: Ok but this will not work if we clean all temp files (cache ...) at the end, because the final image will contain all the layers including the layer where the cache was not cleaned. So it works here but you must pay attention that each layers will be in the final image.

Comment: Paul, explain? I'm saying clean the apt-cache and etc at the end of the `RUN apt-get update...` instruction. Then they will not persist (as they are added _and_ removed before the layer is committed).

Comment: Yes that's OK. You said "after running the commands" so I thought you mean at the end of the Dockerfile

Answer (score 4):

When building an image you're already running as root. You don't need sudo and there's a good chance it's not installed.

Along similar lines, this will never work:

```
RUN sudo cd ansible
```

The `cd` command only affects the current process; this would run `cd` and then exit, leaving you in the same directory you started in.  The Docker `WORKDIR` directive can be used to persistently change the working directory:

```
WORKDIR ansible
```

You can also pass a series of shell commands to the `RUN` directive, like this:

```
RUN cd ansible; source ./hacking/env-setup
```

But even *that* probably won't do what you want, because like the `sudo cd ...` command earlier, that would modify your environment...and then exit, leaving the current environment unchanged in any subsequent commands.

If you want to run Ansible in a container, you should probably either install it, or plan to run the `env-setup` script manually *after* starting a container from the image.