# How to fix 'Error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0' (on dokku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, ubuntu-18.04, dokku

I'm having some trouble while trying to generate an pdf through the `pdf_from_url` method on production.
The error is the following:

```
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge-0.12.5.0/libexec/wkhtmltopdf-linux-amd64: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The line bellow throws the error above:

```rb
   pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_url("https://google.com", {:temp_path => Rails.root.join('public')})
```

The error only occurs on production. Everything works normaly on development.

Running `wkhtmltopdf https://google.com test.pdf` via command line on the server works normally.

One thing to notice is that my application server runs on a dokku container, which i'm inexperienced in. So, probably the error occurs due to the way of how dokku's file architeture works.

What i have already tried:

1. Changed wkhtmltopdf's gem from `wkhtmltopdf-binary` to `wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge`
2. Installed libpng12 manualy on the server (not on dokku container)

What i'm using currently:

wicked_pdf gem version: `1.1.0`

whtmltopdf [provider gem]: `wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge ~> 0.12.5`

platform/distribution and version: Dokku container running on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve that problem by using [dokku-apt](https://github.com/F4-Group/dokku-apt) plugin to install the libpng12.

First, install the dokku-apt plugin on your dokku container:

```
sudo dokku plugin:install https://github.com/F4-Group/dokku-apt
```

Then, create a file named **apt-packages** on your root project directory and insert the name of the lib like:

```
libpng12-0
```

After that, create another file named **apt-repositories** on your root project directory and insert the following line to update your repositories: **(remember to leave an empty line on the end of the file)**

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
```

At last, commit and deploy those files to your dokku container and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve such by installing libpng12-0 from a deb file.

`wget -q -O libpng12.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i libpng12.deb && rm libpng12.deb`

Answer (score 0):

for ubuntu 18.04 you should try

https://github.com/rposborne/wkhtmltopdf-heroku

(even though it says heroku ,it should work for most ubuntu 18.04 environments)

`wkthmltopdf-binary-edge` is not meant to be used outside of dev environments.

if the heroku gem doesn't work for you you could try to downgrade `wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge` to 0.12.4 or 0.12.3. I believe 0.12.5 binary has some issues with 18.04.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried changing to the `wkhtmltopdf-heroku` gem, but it throws the error above:
`Failed to execute:
["/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q", "https://google.com", "/app/public/wicked_pdf_generated_file20190918-9-d35rl0.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
(...)`

Comment: That's odd. It looks like a SSL problem. Could you try to generate a pdf from a local html file?

Comment: I created a simple html file to test that. It worked normally. Also works fine with the `pdf_from_string` method. Any ideas on how to fix that SSL problem?

Comment: Apparently this error should be fixed in wkhtmltopdf's 0.12.5 version acording to wkhtmltopdf's [issue #3001](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3001).

Comment: You could try to reinstall the libssl package in your environment. Otherwise, try lower versions of wkhtmltopdf

Comment: I have tried lower versions of wkhtmltopdf, they also throw this error. Reinstall the libssl package could be a fix, but i don't know how to do that on an dokku container.
Could you give me some directions?

Comment: Hi @LucasVieira Sorry I'm not familiar with Dokku :/ however if you have access to your `Dockerfile` you should be able to install additional packages with `apt-get` command. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273087/how-to-install-multiple-packages-using-apt-get-via-a-dockerfile

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to solve the problem by using [dokku-apt](https://github.com/F4-Group/dokku-apt) plugin to install the libpng12 package on my dokku container.